# Problems getting values from response from wp_remote_post

Tags: json, wp-remote-post

I am using `wp_remote_post` to send a request to a 3rd parti API. The response from the API looks something like:

```
{
  status: 'a',
  member_id: 12345678
}
```

I understand that this is returned in the `body` of the array returned by `wp_remote_post`, but I'm having problems checking the value of `status`. here's what I've got:

```
$response = wp_remote_post($url, $myArr);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Status: ' . json_decode($response['body'])['status'];
}
```

This results in **NOTHING** being `echo`ed. I know the call was successful because I receive the email notification from the 3rd party saying a member was just updated (and I can see the updates in their app). If I change `echo 'Status: ' . json_decode($response['body'])['status'];` to `echo '<pre>' . print_r($response['body']) . '</pre>';`, the object above is printed to screen, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with `json_decode`.

here's the full response, in case it helps:

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [accept-ranges] => bytes
                    [age] => 0
                    [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf8
                    [date] => Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:43:59 GMT
                    [server] => Apache
                    [via] => 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
                    [x-varnish] => 1016917066
                    [content-length] => 48
                )

        )

    [body] => {
  "status": "a", 
  "member_id": 14958539705
}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] => 
    [http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
        (
            [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
                (
                    [body] => {
  "status": "a", 
  "member_id": 14958539705
}
                    [raw] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8
Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:43:59 GMT
Server: Apache
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
x-varnish: 1016917066
Content-Length: 48
Connection: Close

{
  "status": "a", 
  "member_id": 14958539705
}
                    [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [accept-ranges] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => bytes
                                        )

                                    [age] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 0
                                        )

                                    [content-type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => application/json; charset=utf8
                                        )

                                    [date] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:43:59 GMT
                                        )

                                    [server] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Apache
                                        )

                                    [via] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
                                        )

                                    [x-varnish] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 1016917066
                                        )

                                    [content-length] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 48
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [status_code] => 200
                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                    [success] => 1
                    [redirects] => 0
                    [url] => https://api.example.com/191/members/signup
                    [history] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object
                        (
                            [cookies:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [filename:protected] => 
            [data] => 
            [headers] => 
            [status] => 
        )

)
```

Can anyone tell me the correct way to get the value of the `status` property returned in the `body` object of the response?

Comment: You're assuming the response is as you expect, which may not be the case. Have you tried JSON decoding the response and checking that is correct? Rather than assuming it's succesful and trying to access the status index?

Comment: Yeah, `json_decode($response)` produces: **Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...**. I can see from doing `print_r($response)` that the status index is there, the problem is that it is in a json (or json-like) object so I can't access it with `$response['body']['status']`... which is why I thought `json_decode($response['body'])['status'] would work.

Comment: I got it with `json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response))->status`. Is there a better way I should be using?

Comment: I meant check the results of just json decoding, not the `['status']` part. Ideally you want to keep each statement own its own line and avoid smushing steps into a single statement like that. Nested function calls are super frustrating to debug, especially if PHP says there was an error on line 5, and line 5 does lots of things